# Data for Rally Charts do not show using Rally login key model

Tags: rally

I am trying to create an HTML page to access Rally reports external of Rally.  The below code is modified sample code where I am trying to show a burndown chart with my login key, workspace, and project keys removed. When opening the html file, the chart shows, but no data is shown on the chart.  What am I doing wrong?  BTW, if I add this same code in a custom app inside of Rally, the burndown chart shows just fine.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="Name" content="Rally Iteration Burndown Report" />
  <meta name="Version" content="2011.04" />
  <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js?loginKey=MyValidLoginKey"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function initPage() {
      var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("MyValidWorkspaceID","MyValidProjectID","true","false");

       var config = {
           report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.IterationBurndown,
           width : 800,
           height: 400
         };
       var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
       report.display("aDiv");
     }

     rally.addOnLoad(initPage);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add iteration Object ID to the config:

```
iterations: 11111111
```

as in the example below

```
var config = {
    report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.IterationBurndown,
    width : 400,
    height: 300,
    iterations: 111111
};
```

If you have a parent  iteration in the parent project and children iterations in children projects, and you use only the OID of the parent iteration the data will not roll up on its own. If you want the data to aggregate, please use multiple iterations in the config object:

```
iterations: [11111,2222222]
```